# angularJS - evaluation happens too early?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my page I have a table created using ng-repeat directive and the table cells have this code

```html
<span ng-if="row.p3Caption!=''">
                            <img alt="{{row.p3Caption}}" height="32" width="32"
                                 title="{{row.p3Caption}}"
                                 src="{{getImageData(row.dailyPic3, row.p3Caption)}}" />
```

The getImageData has the following code:

```js
$scope.getImageData = function (rowData, fileName) {
            var ext = fileName.split('.').pop();
            if (ext.toLowerCase() == "ico")
                ext = "x-icon";

            return "data:image/" + ext + ";base64," + rowData;            
        };
```

The page looks OK in the browser, e.g. I do see the images in my rows just fine. However, in the Console (in Google Chrome) I see the following error messages:

%7B%7BgetImageData(row.dailyPict,%20row.p1Caption)%7D%7D:1 GET http://localhost:9753/AppName/%7B%7BgetImageData(row.dailyPict,%20row.p1Caption)%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)

I also see this error appear before I finish with my API Controller's code returning the data for the grid.

So, what can I do to avoid these errors in Console, e.g. only evaluate the image source once I get my data?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the evaluation is happening too early may be because the page is loading before it receives the data, but is re-evaluated when the data exists from data binding.

The error that is being posted is saying that it can't find the file where the src is because the path is actually the failed evaluation text.

I believe if you change the `ng-if` to check if it's truthy (bonus: `''` is not truthy). That should make it so the evaluation doesn't occur when `row.p3Caption` is null / undefined.

if `ng-if="row.p3Caption"` doesn't work try `ng-if="!!row.p3Caption"`

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. In both cases I still got the error :(
<span ng-if="!!row.p1Caption" class="ng-scope">
                           <span><!-- ngIf: !!row.p1Caption --><img height="32" width="32" ng-if="!!row.p1Caption" alt="ACCESS.ICO" title="ACCESS.ICO" src="data:image/x-icon;base64," class="ng-scope"><!-- end ngIf: !!row.p1Caption --></span>

Comment: My idea is to add the image only when I do have a fileName in the p1Caption. Otherwise don't show the image. The value in the row.p1Caption will be an empty string in this case.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhat different. It's the { which is being converted the first time into unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by looking into our solution and searching for src= in chtml files. I have to use ng-src instead of the src. Using ng-src helped to get rid of the error.